# virtual midi port route in rasbian

Tags: linux, terminal, alsa, raspbian, midi

I'm trying to create virtual midi port on rpi3 with one channel input and one output.

I'm first creating a virtual port using

```
$ modprobe snd-virmidi snd_index=1
```

which I can see is created using

```
$ aconnect -lio
client 0: 'System' [type=kernel]
0 'Timer           '
1 'Announce        '
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]
0 'Midi Through Port-0'
client 20: 'Virtual Raw MIDI 1-0' [type=kernel]
0 'VirMIDI 1-0     '
client 21: 'Virtual Raw MIDI 1-1' [type=kernel]
0 'VirMIDI 1-1     '
client 22: 'Virtual Raw MIDI 1-2' [type=kernel]
0 'VirMIDI 1-2     '
client 23: 'Virtual Raw MIDI 1-3' [type=kernel]
0 'VirMIDI 1-3     '
```

and then try to route 21 to 20 using

```
$ aconnect 21:0 20:0
```

which seems successful

```
$ aconnect -l
...
client 20: 'Virtual Raw MIDI 1-0' [type=kernel]
0 'VirMIDI 1-0     '
    Connected From: 21:0
client 21: 'Virtual Raw MIDI 1-1' [type=kernel]
0 'VirMIDI 1-1     '
    Connecting To: 20:0
```

then when I'm trying to dump contents of ch 20 in one terminal window via

```
$ amidi -p hw:1,0 -d
```

and sending raw midi using another terminal

```
$ amidi -p hw:1,1 -S 'A0'
```

I'm not getting anything on my first terminal no matter how long the byte sequence or values I type. Finally I just terminate read via ctrl+c and it terminates with following message

```
^C
0 bytes read
```

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong or is it even possible via virtual midi?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to build a midi hub between 2 usb-midi devices and some digital switches to alter messages depending on value. I was hoping to use virtual midi ports to stimulate bytes and read response while developing interface as it cumbersome to have both hw plugged in all the time.

Comment: Do you want to use the ALSA sequencer, or an OSS MIDI device?

Comment: I was planning to use ALSA sequencer

Answer (score 1):

The `snd-virmidi` driver is a bridge between ALSA sequencer ports and OSS MIDI ports.

To get loopback ports (that send back what they receive), use the `snd-seq-dummy` driver. It's loaded automatically; you already have the "Midi Through Port".

Comment: and how does one send to this port. Please elaborate. for example is `amidi -p"Midi Through" .....` correct?

Comment: @nass `amidi` works only with RawMIDI ports. Use `aplaymidi` or pretty much any other program.